How to handle an exeption within onException and propagate to errorHandler in Apache Camel?
I'm running in a case, where an exception occurs because of a database outage,
then the onException handler is called, which tries to store a message in the database and updates some status, which obviously also fails because of the outage.
I'd like to have an additional global exception handler, that is used as a fallback. And declared it using errorHandler()
This is the onException handler that produces the failure, and I came up with an idea:

By setting handled to false in case of a failure, the exception should be propagated upwards to the next handler.

I start the onException clause with handled(false), run the processors and if no exception happened, the handled(exchange -> true)
However, the execution order is different here! See the numbers attached to each line
      //would love to catch here
      errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("direct:errorRoute")
        .maximumRedeliveries(1) // Optional: set redelivery attempts
        .onRedelivery(exchange -> {
           log.debug("Redelivery");
         })
      );
        
        //or here
        onException(Throwable.class)
          .process(exchange -> {
            //not called
          });

        //or here
        from("direct:errorRoute")
            .routeId("errorRoute")
            .process(exchange -> {
                   //not called
                });

        from("actual-route")
           //exception handler failing because of database outage
           .onException(Exception.class)
              //delegate to top-level by default
              .handled(false)
  
              .process(notifier::notify)#2
              .process(tracker::onProcessingFailed) //#3 this fails

              //Idea: Only executed when all process commands run without exception
              .handled(exchange -> true) #1
           .end()
           .process(processorFailingBecauseDatabaseOutage)

The top-level error handlers are never called and instead, the FatalFallbackErrorHandler is called
What do I have to do to propagate the exception successfully to the top-level handlers?

Here is some words about an exception being thrown inside dead letter channel.
Apache Camel - Dead Letter Channel
As an alternative, what about using an additional exception clause.
        from("timer:test-timer?repeatCount=1")
        .onException(Exception.class)
            .handled(true)
            .log("Local Exception!")
            .onException(Exception.class)
                .log("Manage specific process exception")
            .end()
            .throwException(new CamelException("Process Exception"))
        .end()
        .throwException(new IllegalArgumentException("DB Outage Exception"))
        .log("Not Getting here!");

If this does not convince you, I would use a try-catch in your process and send the exception/exchange using a ProducerTemplate.
    from("direct:error-log")
        // Handle the Exception
        .log("Exception: ${exception}");

    from("timer:test-timer?repeatCount=1")
        .onException(Exception.class)
            .handled(true)
            .log("Local Exception!")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    try {
                        throw new CamelException("Process Exception");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        exchange.setProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, e);
                        exchange.getContext()
                            .createProducerTemplate()
                            .send("direct:error-log", exchange);
                    }
                }
            })
        .end()
        .throwException(new IllegalArgumentException("DB Outage Exception"))
        .log("Not Getting here!");

Anyways, let me know your opinion.
Regards.
